# Date format not displaying in Ejs as it is in backend moment.js

Tags: node.js, momentjs, ejs

I'm using a backend POST request that is creating a post:

```
router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {

var name = req.body.name;
var image = req.body.image;
var description = req.body.description;
var text = req.body.text;
var author = {
    id: req.user._id,
    username: req.user.username
}

var postedTime = req.body.date;
let createdOn = moment(postedTime).format('DD MM YYYY').toString();
console.log(createdOn);

var newPost = {
    name: name,
    image: image,
    description: description,
    text: text,
    author: author,
    createdOn: createdOn
}
spacePost.create(newPost, function(err, newlyCreated) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.redirect("/spaceblog")

    }
})
```

I'm using moment.js to format the date, and the console looks fine (02 10 2018). However at the moment of passing it to the ejs in views, it appears again as timestamp.

```
Posted on Sat Oct 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)
```

Code for retrieving it on EJS

```
<div class="card-footer text-muted">
      Posted on
      <%= post.createdOn  %>
</div>
```

I read that a solution would be to use moment(). in the EJS calling it with the script inside (I have the script in the header already too). However I would have to render in backend the main page (passing the moment object) instead of redirect, but I didn't find a way to do it without cancelling the POST action for the creation of the post.
I didn't find a helpful doc in momentjs.com

Comment: What database do you use? How do you save a new post? How do you get post data for a template `spaceblog` and how do you transfer it to a template?

Comment: mongoDB; the new post is saved while using the .create in the function ; the POST is in JS code (update  in the description here above)
the .post is passing the post to the template

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it now actually, for anyone who will have the same issue. No need to insert moment.js script in the view page if you're using Nodejs. Call Moment in backend for your date:

```
let createdOn = moment(postedTime).toString();
```

then add to the app.js (or whataver name you have for the main route)

```
app.locals.moment = require('moment');
```

then you can call and format with Moment in the EJS:

```
<%= moment(post.createdOn).format('DD MM YYYY');  %>
```